# how to set enabled or disabled scrolling in scroll view based on the text view content size?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

[image]

I am trying to make a view controller that has a scroll view and text view. I want my scrolling is enabled only when the text content of the text view is a lot. because it seems ugly if I can scroll my view controller even though the text content in the text view is not to much like the picture below

[image]

as we can see there is a big gap to the bottom of view controller. this is the code I use for this VC

```
import UIKit

class NotificationDetailVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var notificationTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var notificationImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var notificationDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var notificationContentTextView: UITextView!

    var dataNotification : [String:Any]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateUI()
        updateReadStatusInUserDefault()
    }

    @IBAction func imageDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let popup = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageDisplay") as! ReusableImageDisplayVC
        popup.photo = notificationImage.image
        self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func updateUI() {
        guard let dataNotification = dataNotification else {return}
        notificationTitleLabel.text = dataNotification["Judul"] as? String
        notificationContentTextView.text = dataNotification["Keterangan"] as? String

        guard let notifDate = dataNotification["TglNotif"] as? String else {return}
        notificationDateLabel.text = DateTimeService.changeFormat(of: notifDate, toFormat: "d MMM YYY")

        let imagePath = dataNotification["Photo"] as? String
        guard let encodedImagePath = imagePath?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) else {return}

        if imagePath != nil {
            if imagePath!.isEmpty {
                notificationImage.removeFromSuperview()
            } else {
                notificationImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: encodedImagePath), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "3-2 Img"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload])
            }
        } else {
            notificationImage.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func updateReadStatusInUserDefault() {
        guard let dataNotification = dataNotification,
            let notifID = dataNotification["notif_id"] as? Int else {return}

        guard var readNotificationStatusUserDefault  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "readNotification") as? [String:String] else {return}

        readNotificationStatusUserDefault["\(notifID)"] = "1"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(readNotificationStatusUserDefault, forKey: "readNotification")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Comment: you should change your scrollview content size based on your textview text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to find size of text of your **textview**,
you can find size of text using :

```
func rectForText(text: String, font: UIFont, maxSize: CGSize) -> CGSize
{
    let attrString = NSAttributedString.init(string: yourtext, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:font])
    let rect = attrString.boundingRect(with: maxSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
    let size = CGSize(width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height)//(, )
    return size
}
```

after that set size of your **textview** according to your text size :

```
let contentSize : CGSize = rectForText(text: str, font:UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0) , maxSize : CGSize(width: 200 * (SCREEN_WIDTH / 320), height: 20000) )
```

and set frame of your textview

```
var frame = self.myTextView.frame
frame.size.height = contentSize.height
self.myTextView.frame = frame
```

after set set contentsize of your scrollview

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: myTextView.frame.size.height + 8)
```

Hope this help! Happy coding :)

Answer (score -2):

Depending upon the `contentSize` of text view, adjust the scrollable property of scroll view.

After setting the text on textview, check as below:-

```
    let height = self.notificationContentTextView.contentSize.height
if(height > scrollView.frame.size.height){
scrollView.isScrollEnabled == true
}else{
scrollView.isScrollEnabled == false
}
```

Comment: I think The problem is related to setting scrollView contentSize to textView+ Other View's height.